# xcodebuild: error: Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action

Tags: ios, flutter

Xcode build done.                                            3.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
xcodebuild: error: Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

Flutter Doctor output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.3.0-0.5.pre, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.3.0-0.5.pre on channel beta at /Users/alisinancobani/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 096162697a (4 weeks ago), 2022-08-22 15:34:14 -0700
    • Engine revision ad3d868e0d
    • Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-271.7.beta)
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alisinancobani/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A309
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 70.0.5
    • Dart plugin version 222.4167.21

[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.48.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • Ali Sinan’s iPhone (mobile) • 00008030-000E0C4A3E91802E            • ios            • iOS 16.0 20A362
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile)  • 1E48649C-6F45-40F0-BE09-F881EAA1443C • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 105.0.5195.125

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
2. Product > Scheme > Managed Schemes
3. Select Runner > Edit...
4. In the Build tab are any Targets selected?
5. Do you see this little checkmark?

[image]

Ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47261#issuecomment-567202724

If you don't see, you can try add manually or use `flutter create .` in the root of your project to restore the configs.